# Use of another class repository inside other class controller is right way or calling api using RestTemplate class is right way

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

this is my post controller before posting any content i want to fetch particular user

```
@RequestMapping("/post")

public class PostController {

   @Autowired
   private PostRepository postRepository;

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;
   ....
   ....
   .... 
}
```

Comment: Use the repository, don't call the REST API itself, this is really inefficient and not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to, you should have repository used only in your service classes. Like `PostRepository in PostService` not in controller. So I would prefer you can write service and use that service class in controller rather using repository directly in controller.

Do not need REST call for this purpose.